# Classification of states in Markov Chain

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, markov-process, ergodic

**Question**

Consider the following transition matrix:

```
 P= 
 0     0     1     0     0     0 
 0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0
1/4   1/4    0    1/2    0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0
 0    1/3    0     0     0    2/3
```

**a)** Which states are transient?
**b)** Which states are recurrent?
**c)** Identify all closed sets of states.
**d)** Is this chain ergodic?

Dear friends ,

I have thought the states are as follows,
{1,5} {0,2,4} recurrent since they communicate with each other
{3} transient

and since state 3 does not communicate with other states, it is not an ergodic Mc

Am I correct?

Thank you..

Comment: What is your reasoning?  PS Please format your question for readability; see http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help.

Comment: Dear @whuber , I don't know how to write matrix.It is not mentioned in the link also :/

Comment: I have at least roughly fixed the matrix for you, by selecting the text for the matrix and then clicking on the $\{\}$ symbol to make it monospaced text and then lining it up.

Comment: This is a question more appropriate to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stochastic processes is a subject of statistics rather than 'math'
math is deterministic,stat is stochastic.
thx

Comment: @StocSim I think the relevant determinant of what makes a question appropriate on CV is the scope given in the faq; that would be the basis on which to argue that it belongs here rather than math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Let the state space of the Markov Chain be $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Now draw the state transition diagram.

[image]

(a). From the figure, we observe that $\{4\}$, and $\{6\}$ form non-closed communicating classes. State $2$ does not communicate even with itself and such a state is called a **non-return** state. Hence, the states **2**, **4** and **6** are **transient**.

(b)&(c). The class $\{1,3,5\}$ is a closed-communicating class. Hence, states **1**, **3** and **5** are recurrent states.

(c). There is only one closed-communicating class, $\{1,3,5\}$.

(d). As the chain is not an irreducible Markov Chain, it is not an ergodic chain.